# How to include js files on a vuejs component?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm just started to study how to do an laravel api with vuejs framework and I have a lot of doubts. On of them is: how can I include js files on a specific vue component? Nowadays, I'm importing all my js files on index of my vue client but what I whised it's how to load specific js file on its specific vue component. I've already tried `require('assets/path/to/jsfile')`, `import('assets/path/to/jfsile')` and nothing works.

For example:

in my folders I have this structure: `myapp -> static -> myjsfolder -> myjsfile`

and in my vue-component I want to import my `myjsfile`. The admin template I'm using is AdminLTE, laravel as backend and webpack as client on vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

Are your js files exporting anything?

If so, try using:

```
import * as Something from 'assets/path/to/jsfile'
```

The path will be relative to the component so you may need to use `./` or `../path` for example.

Edit: Does the following work? Assuming a single file component is being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some/js/file.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
    export default {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Within `teste.js` either add a function:

```
function printToConsole() {
    console.log('working')
}
```

then later call `printToConsole()` within your component.

or use an IIFE

```
(function () {
    console.log('working')
 })()
```

Comment: Not. Some of them don't export anything. That's the problem. As they export nothing I have to import them on my index. So, all my js files are on index.html. That sucks!

Comment: Can you just require them in a normal `<script>` tag?

Comment: Nops, even when I put the full path to the file my vue component doesn't execute it. <script src="http://localhost:8080/static/dist/teste.js"></script>. This file shows a console message only.

Comment: can you post the contents of `teste.js`? You made need to wrap it's contents in an immediately invoked function to get it to execute right away.

Comment: Ok, nothing is invoking the script then. You either need to wrap it in a function and call the function or wrap the contents in an immediately invoked function like `(function () { console.log('working')})()`